# Optical Path across a slab

Tags: optics

When a slab is placed in front of one of the slits of YDSE , the path difference irrespective of position of point on screen is always written as `Mue-1`t. Shouldn't be only when the light travels exactly perpendicular to the slab. Is it true that optical paths across slab is true for any angle with which it travels across the slab. Thank you

Comment: Your understanding is correct: for an accurate calculation, the angle of light propagation through the slab needs to be taken into account.

Comment: Thank you. So does all the books make it as an assumption without any reason ? Is the reason that they should pointing out is that the slab thickness is very small ?

Comment: If the slab is upstream from the slit, and the incident beam is collimated, then there is no angle difference to account for.

Comment: In a YDSE we say the holes are pin holes , so does the case of collimated beam arise ? And moreover when you say a collimated beam we mostly talk about the light traveling like rays and consider their pathe differences. Thank you

Comment: Upstream means on the side closest to the source, before the pinholes or slits.

Comment: Ok thank you. May be I need to dwell a little deeper into it coz none of the books mention about the approximation or phase difference being independent of the angle.

Comment: Your intuition in this case is correct.